# How to find inverse relationship in laravel models using tinker

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I got this class

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RetailerInfo extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        //same as retailer() but more consistent
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'retailer_id');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
    }
}
```

Finding the retailer belonging to the store works just fine:

```
>>>namespace App;
>>>Store::find(2)->RetailerInfo
=> App\RetailerInfo {#1144
     id: 1,
     retailer_id: 65,
     store_id: 2,
     created_at: "2016-07-16 09:47:43",
     updated_at: "2016-07-16 09:47:43",
   }
```

but finding the user that a store belongs to doesn't work:

```
>>> RetailerInfo::find(1)->belongsTo(User::class)
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {#1176}
>>> RetailerInfo::find(1)->belongsTo(User::class, 'retailer_id')
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: W'll need to see your User and Store classes, to see how you are declaring the inverse relations. Which seems to be one to one!. I recommend checking this Eloquent Relationships Cheat Sheet, and retry https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209

Comment: Your call for the retailer in tinker is fine - Store::find(2)->RetailerInfo. Your call for the user uses a different pattern - RetailerInfo::find(1)->belongsTo(User::class) and attempts to define a relationship.  Should you not call it in the same way? i.e RetailerInfo::find(1)->User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) says, you only need to declare the relation once, and inside a method of the model

What you're doing with this example

```
RetailerInfo::find(1)->belongsTo(User::class);
```

Is incorrect because you don't declare relations on the go.

Instead use the relations you already declared in your models (`Store` has a relation with `RetailerInfo`, and `RetailerInfo` already has a relation with `User`)

```
Store::find(2)->RetailerInfo->user;
```

Comment: um.. can you tell me more? ie provide reference or something?